# Need help verifying understanding of convexity (concavity) + quasi convexity(quasi concavity)

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I wanted to verify the definition of quasi concavity/convexity. In my textbooks it says a function is quasi concave if the upper contour set is convex. It also says a function is quasi concave if f(λx+(1−λ)y) ≥ min {f(x), f(y)}.
If I use [f(x)=|x|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ0bu.jpg) to show this, we can see visually that the upper contour set is obviously convex, suggesting quasi concavity but if you take values x and y on the domain and use the definition f(λx+(1−λ)y) ≥ min {f(x), f(y)}, we can see that a part of f(λx+(1−λ)y) makes this statement untrue.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: So actually $f(x)=|x|$ is convex (and quasiconvex), not concave (or quasiconcave). If you try verifying this definition for $f(x)=-|x|$, you may have more luck :-)